# SQL Insert Query With Condition Exception

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have this query:

```
 String requete = "INSERT INTO reduction(newPrix) VALUES (?) "
                        + "WHERE id_prom=? AND id_prod=?";
```

I am getting an exception:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHERE id_prom=2 AND id_prod=6' at line 1

I'm wondering why the INSERT query was failing. Any advise appreciated.

Comment: You can try to use `INSERT INTO .... SELECT`

Comment: Do you really want to insert a new row in the table? This is what INSERT INTO does.

Comment: INSERT has no WHERE. Do you want UPDATE?

Comment: your SQL looks like an amalgamation of an update and in insert - which are you trying to do?

Comment: i used update inplace of insert and it worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert a row into your table.
This means that you need to specify all mandatory values (i.e. values for the columns that are not nullable and don't have a default value).
You can't use a where clause in this kind of insert statement. What would it mean? And in your program you can verify the validity of the data you'd like to add to your table and decide to insert or not.

Comment: yes indeed i change it to update and i worked thanks